# Нужно ли в заданном примере текста второе тире?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, пунктуация

"Даже когда Николай Ростов проиграл крупную сумму денег в карты и выбор у него оставался один - выплатить долг или застрелиться, - его отец Илья Ильич не стал упрекать сына и читать ему нудные натации"
Нужно ли здесь второе тире или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Вот что пишет Розенталь, правда о несогласованных определениях, выраженных неопределенной формой глагола, перед которой можно без ущерба для смысла поставить слова *а именно*:

"Если по условиям контекста после определения должна стоять запятая, то второе тире обычно опускается:** ***Так как оставался один выбор — потерять армию и Москву или одну Москву, то фельдмаршал должен был выбрать последнее*** (Л.Т.)".

У нас очень похожее предложение: *Когда выбор у него оставался один - выплатить долг или застрелиться, - его отец Илья Ильич не стал упрекать сына.* Только инфинитивная часть относится к сказуемому.

Чуть-чуть изменить - и будет иллюстрация правила: *Когда у него оставался один выбор - выплатить долг или застрелиться, его отец Илья Ильич не стал упрекать сына*.

Я не нахожу формального подтверждения тому, что в анализируемом варианте можно опустить тире, но я бы его не ставила.

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу надобности во втором тире. Но следует обратить внимание на орфографию слова нотация. Проверочное слово - блокнот.

Answer (score 0):

Да, тире нужно, постановка знаков препинания здесь независимая.

Два тире обособляют присоединительную часть составного именного сказуемого (выплатить долг или застрелиться), а запятая  ставится между придаточными предложениями, связанными союзом И, и главным предложением.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ НА ТЕМУ "КАК У РОЗЕНТАЛЯ"

Нет никаких сомнений, что уважаемый Д. Э. Розенталь пользовался тремя основными принципами пунктуации, когда решал свои практические  задачи. Вот бы и нам тоже! Но мы имеем только ответы-правила, но не объяснения решенных задач, и  поэтому приходится искать у Розенталя ПОХОЖИЕ примеры, чтобы расставить знаки препинания ПОХОЖИМ образом (и обязательно какая-то  мелочь не совпадает и доказательство портит). А просто сказать, что не нужно там тире или  нужно там тире, – это как-то неубедительно ни для себя, ни для окружающих.  Но ведь можно поступить иначе: ОБЪЯСНИТЬ уже решенные задачи и научиться их решать самим.

Итак, мы разбираем заданное предложение, а вот и  похожий пример: «Так как оставался один выбор – потерять армию и Москву или одну Москву, то фельдмаршал должен был выбрать последнее».

1. СРАВНИВАЕМ два варианта и делаем вывод: пример у Розенталя ДЛЯ ОБОБЩЕНИЯ не слишком удачный, так как в нем просто НЕЛЬЗЯ ПОСТАВИТЬ второе тире: «Так как оставался один выбор – потерять армию и Москву или одну Москву, – то фельдмаршал должен был выбрать последнее». Не очень симпатично получается, так как тире мы поставили перед второй частью подчинительного союза.
2. Тогда попробуем рассмотреть ОБЩЕЕ РЕШЕНИЕ подобных примеров, так как в различных синтаксических конструкциях встречаются ОБА ВАРИАНТА (одно тире и два тире).

А)  Независимая постановка тире (два тире, интонация ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЯ):
«Когда тайный договор был заключен – его всё-таки пришлось закрепить на бумаге, – великое посольство собралось к отъезду».   «Все мы, воспитатели –  учителя и вожатые, –  должны много работать с детьми».

Б)   ВСТРОЕННАЯ интонация (второе тире поглощается запятой):  «Дня через два, выходя садиться в карету с графиней – большой любительницей ездить по гостям, она заметила фигуру офицера».  «Я зачитался книгой – письмами Ван-Гога, когда в дверь постучали».

1. РЕШЕНИЕ. С одной стороны,  в нашем примере лучше использовать встроенную интонацию с одним тире, так как вставка тесно сливается с местоимением «один» (паузы там практически нет). С другой стороны,  значительно распространенную придаточную часть (два однородных придаточных + вставка)  и главное предложение очень желательно РАЗДЕЛИТЬ АВТОРСКОЙ ПАУЗОЙ И ТИРЕ.

   ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Постановка такого авторского тире – вещь вполне легитимная даже  в малораспространенных предложениях, например: Сколько бы ни смотреть на море – оно никогда не надоест.  Коли ты честный – не водись с бесчестными. Когда идёшь над бездной – надо прямо смотреть в лазурь и свет.
2. ВЫВОД. Итак, предложение явно распадается на две смысловые части, которые мы разделяем паузой и тире.  Назначение знаков пунктуации в том и заключается, чтобы делать нашу речь выразительной и понятной, и совсем не в том, чтобы соответствовать формальным правилам, смысл которых неясен пользователям.

   Но вы приняли другое решение и считаете, что можно обойтись без паузы и тире? Это ваше право, но вы должны объяснить свой выбор. Так что же реально, без Розенталя, с вашей точки зрения, дает вам постановка или отсутствие тире?
3. ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ. И наконец, подводя итог,  хотелось бы пожелать нашей науке, чтобы она не имела вид  УСЛОВНОГО СОГЛАШЕНИЯ-ДОГОВОРЕННОСТИ, а давала бы автору возможность  найти наилучшую форму для выражения его мыслей. И очень хотелось бы (хотя бы в обозримом будущем), чтобы ОБОСНОВАНИЕ решения было связано с содержанием текста, а не делалось бы по принципу «сравниваем наше предложение с другим предложением и выбираем такой же знак».